# Text Reader With a WebCam

Tags: c#, text, webcam

I'm making a Windows Application that translate text from Italian to English. I searched on the internet how to read a text printed on an object using a webcam in C# but I couldn't find it.
How can I took a frame from a vide, analaize it an grab a text to convert into a string?

Comment: [help] contains informations on what kind of questions you should ask here. Please read it.

Comment: You are looking for OCR software

Comment: Look into [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) software (or write your own OCR.) Just capture a picture from the WebCam and run it thru OCR. Of course quality all depends on how effective the OCR software is

Comment: Yes. I think I'm looking for an OCR DLL. My idea is to took video from WebCam (I also need webcam DLL) and OCR'd it. I don't know it is possible.

Comment: I don't want to be a pain in your back, but now you have changed your question from 'recommend me a tool' to 'too broad to be answered without writing a book'. You need to do some research by yourself, try some library or example stuff and ask a specific question when (if) you are stuck.

Comment: google c# OCR - there are several open source implementation. And there are many commercial ones too

Comment: Check for my answer, if that's what you want please mark as answered.

Comment: Is that FREE? I will try it. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like Cloud OCR SDK

http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/cs/

Another post with the same question here: [Where can i find a free .Net (C#) library that i can use to scan and OCR documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459013/where-can-i-find-a-free-net-c-library-that-i-can-use-to-scan-and-ocr-documen)

Also another similar question you may find useful: [How to implement and do OCR in a C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947399/how-to-implement-and-do-ocr-in-a-c-sharp-project)