# How to get text from image using C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

I am trying to figure out how to get text from an image programmatically using a .NET language, preferably C#.

I know that there are several free softwares available out there that will extract text from images, and I have MS OneNote.  OneNote seems to work fine for me to extract the text, but I don't know how to do it programmatically, only using the user interface.

The rest of the processing I want to do from there I can figure out on my own, but I need the code to get an OCR program like OneNote to open a PDF from a folder location, read the scanned image in the PDF, convert it to text, and save the text into an array for further processing.

Comment: It is called OCR (Optical Character Recognition). You can try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947399/how-to-implement-and-do-ocr-in-a-c-sharp-project#answer-27385157 He provided an instruction there

Comment: Thanks Jacky, I have figured out the first part of solving my problem now, which was to import the OCR library into my Visual Studio project.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to extract text from images in PDF's in a local folder.  Unfortunately this thread has now been marked as a duplicate, but what others have suggested so far as answers do not help much in solving my dilemma.  They are answers of a much larger scope, or they implement a user interface, which I do not want.

Comment: Hi, Have you try the answers by @B.K. (the url in my previous commment go straight to his answer). His answer is quite simple, as after he imported the lib to projects, he just write a simple Console App to work with that OCR. What lib are you add in your project?

Comment: I have voted to reopen so that the correct duplicate can be identified. This question IS a duplicate, but I think it has been marked as a dupe of the wrong question. The linked dupe is much more specific and is actually asking something quite different. The correct dupe is stackoverflow.com/questions/10947399/… . I can't flag this directly because it is already closed. Linking to the wrong question is harmful to future readers. Following guidance on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252844/incorrect-wrong-duplicate-question