# pictureBox how to get the area with numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I want to clip image and keep the area with numbers of machine.First of all,i think,the good idea is invert image,but i dont know what to do in the next.Screenshot below

[screenshow what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn9Mu.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to just get the numbers/letters from the initial picture?

Comment: i am trying to find this numbers and letters,after i want to recognize it

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are trying to do is implement some sort of `optical character recognition`.

A good place to start is: [How to implement and do OCR in a C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947399/how-to-implement-and-do-ocr-in-a-c-sharp-project)

You might also be trying to [simply `crop` the image in c#.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)

Comment: Can i write something similar,but not using other libs?

Comment: You could but in my opinion you are reinventing wheel if you make your own OCR. You are trying to make your own car tho, and having the wheels work properly and tested properly helps..Also I think that would take very long.