# OCR : C#/.net for Extract URL from Image

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, ocr

Can any one help me to extract only URL from image when doing images processing OCR.

I checked, all OCR dll are in paid version. Is there any free libraries.

Comment: Look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947399/how-to-implement-and-do-ocr-in-a-c-sharp-project

Comment: Try Interop.MODI.dll , its from  microsoft

Comment: @Sund'er, already checked given link. All are paid.

Comment: No answer without sample images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used IronOCR and problem solve. I created GetText Function which fetch URL from text when image converted to text.

```
 IronTesseract IronOcr = new IronTesseract();
            var Result = IronOcr.Read(Path.GetTempPath() +  "image.png");
            string _url = GetText(Result.Text);


 private string GetText(string myString)
    {
       Match url = Regex.Match(myString, @"[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@%_\+.~#?&//=]*)");
        return url.ToString();
    }
```